# TCPDF: setPage then addPage doesnt really create a new page between existing ones

Tags: php, tcpdf

i create a complex PDF with TCPDF which is working like a charm.

Now i have about 230 pages and want to create an index. That index cannot be created using the TOCPage function, because i have my own design i wanna use. As the page number are know only by adding pages and putting stuff on it, i cannot only build the index during pdf creation.
So at the end i use the setPage function to jump to the first or second page, then start creating my index by using addPage. But this unfortunately simply jumps to the next page and overwrites it with my index stuff.

The code is pretty simple, the code below has the same structure like mines. The index is created without any problems looking good. But it overwrites my existing pages.

Any idea how to add page IN BETWEEN existing pages?

```
$pdf = new PDF(); // <-- my pdf class extending from TCPDF
// add stuff using multicell, cell or anything else
$pdf->setPage( 2); // jump back to page 2 as we have an array containing the index
foreach( $my_index as $index) {
  $pdf->addPage();
  // add index stuff on new page which should start at page 3, all other existing pages should move forward
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: `Any idea how to add page IN BETWEEN existing pages?` I don't think so. Because pdf document compiled like a stream. But Do U try: $pdf->addPage(); $pdf->write(10, '1'); $pdf->addPage(); $pdf->write(10, '2'); foreach( $my_index as $index) { .. } than jump to $pdf->setPage(1); // and write here?

Comment: I think addPage doesnt allow me to create a new page. It just simply jumps to the next page if there is one.